# Hi in snowflake sql I would like to extract string after '\' character

Tags: string, substring, character

I have a string 'TEST.COM\GUEST.PARKING'.  I would like to extract 'GUEST.PARKING' out of it. So I want to extract string/characters after '' character.

I tried the following statement and gets the error
select SUBSTRING('TEST.COM\GUEST.PARKING',CHARINDEX('','TEST.COM\GUEST.PARKING')+1,LEN('TEST.COM\GUEST.PARKING'))

Error:

Syntax error: unexpected 'TEST'. (line 78)
syntax error line 1 at position 61 unexpected '.'.
parse error line 1 at position 66 near '71'.
parse error line 1 at position 98 near '71'.
parse error line 1 at position 114 near ''. (line 78)

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT SPLIT_PART('TEST.COM\GUEST.PARKING', '\', 2) AS extracted_string;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    column1
  , split_part(column1, '\\', 2) as extracted_string
from values('TEST.COM\\GUEST.PARKING');
```

Comment: Could perhaps talk about how you need to escape the `\` with another `\`, leading to `\\` appearing instead of `\` in strings.

Comment: @Dragon I couldn't get you.